# Matching nginx locations starting with letter i

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm having a problem with location blocks starting with "i".

The following location block is not matched by requesting "/" (and this is the expected result)

```
location /h {
    return 302 /redirect-for-testing-purposes ;
}
```

but this other one, starting with "i", is matched by requesting "/"

```
location /i {
    return 302 /redirect-for-testing-purposes ;
}
```

Note that this behavior occurs only with the letter "i", and you can test it with the following location blocks:

This location block will not be matched by requesting "/"

```
location ~* ^/([a-h]|[j-z]) {
    return 302 /redirect-for-testing-purposes ;
}
```

whilst this will

```
location ~* ^/[a-z] {
    return 302 /redirect-for-testing-purposes ;
}
```

What's going on here that I could not figure out?
Thanks.

nginx version: 1.14.0 and 1.12.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is also the first letter of `index.html`.

When you access a URI like `/`, the `index` directive will internally rewrite the URI to `/index.html`.

After an internal rewrite, `nginx` will begin another search for a matching `location` block and finds your `location /i` block.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for more.